# Associate Elastic IPs with EKS worker nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've just successfully followed [AWS EKS Getting Started Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html), and now I have operational Kubernetes cluster of 3 worker nodes.

Worker node EC2 instances have auto-assigned public IPs:

```
IPv4 Public IP: 18.197.201.199
Private IPs: 192.168.180.57, 192.168.148.90
Secondary private IPs: 192.168.170.137, 192.168.180.185, 192.168.161.170, 192.168.133.109, 192.168.182.189, 192.168.189.234, 192.168.166.204, 192.168.156.144, 192.168.133.148, 192.168.179.151
```

In order to connect to private off-AWS resources, firewall rules require node public IPs be from specific pool of Elastic IPs. (More specifically, worker nodes must access private Docker registry behind the corporate firewall, which white-lists several AWS Elastic IPs.) The simplest seems to override auto-assigned public node IPs with pre-defined Elastic IPs; however AWS allows to associate Elastic IP only with a specific private IP.

How do I proceed to replace auto-assigned public IPs with Elastic IPs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that nodes can come and go.

You wouldn't want a specific node in your cluster configured to an Elastic IP that was cleared for your off-AWS resource(s).

Instead you would have a NAT Gateway assigned an Elastic IP and cluster node(s) in a private subnet that use that NAT Gateway for outbound communication.

This configuration is described beginning on page 85 of this pdf.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-ug.pdf

Comment: What if you start a worker that processes like 200GB per day? Using a NAT gateway would cause extra costs of around $300 per month. Can't you just associate an EIP to the pod? I tried but it failed because the instance has multiple network interfaces.

Comment: Pod is disposable. Today you have acme.com with 3 pods, tomorrow 1, and day after tomorrow, 5 pods